# Problem with blinking a led with bluetooth in arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32, led

i am trying to make a program that turns on ,off and blinks an led with the help from  bluetooth
On and of were pretty easy to replicate,but i can't make the blink to work.There are to options either blinks once,either if i ad a while it never stops from looping.i tried with both if and case.Can somebody help me.I am using an esp32.
The code with if:

```c++
    #include "BluetoothSerial.h"
    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <analogWrite.h>
    
    #if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
    #error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
    #endif
    
    BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
    int received;// received value will be stored in this variable
    char receivedChar;// received value will be stored as CHAR in this variable
    
    const char turnON ='a';
    const char turnOFF ='b';
    const char turnBLINK= 'c';
    //const char turnFADE='d';
    const int LEDpin = 12;
    //int brightStep = 1;
    //int brightness = 0;
    
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      SerialBT.begin("Mono"); //Bluetooth device name
      Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
      Serial.println("To turn ON send: a");//print on serial monitor  
      Serial.println("To turn OFF send: b"); //print on serial monitor 
      pinMode(LEDpin, OUTPUT);
     // analogWriteResolution(LEDpin, 12);
     
    }
    
    void loop() {
        receivedChar =(char)SerialBT.read();
    
      if (Serial.available()) {
        SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
      
      }
      if (SerialBT.available()) {
       // while(SerialBT.available()){
      //  receivedChar =(char)SerialBT.read();
      //  }
        
        SerialBT.print("Received:");// write on BT app
        SerialBT.println(receivedChar);// write on BT app      
        Serial.print ("Received:");//print on serial monitor
        Serial.println(receivedChar);//print on serial monitor    
        //SerialBT.println(receivedChar);//print on the app    
        //SerialBT.write(receivedChar); //print on serial monitor
        if(receivedChar == turnON)
        {
         SerialBT.println("LED ON:");// write on BT app
         Serial.println("LED ON:");//write on serial monitor
         digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);// turn the LED ON
           
        }
        if(receivedChar == turnOFF)
        {
         SerialBT.println("LED OFF:");// write on BT app
         Serial.println("LED OFF:");//write on serial monitor
          digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);// turn the LED off 
        }    
          if(receivedChar == turnBLINK)
        {
         SerialBT.println("LED blink:");// write on BT app
         Serial.println("LED blink:");//write on serial monitor
         while (receivedChar == turnBLINK){
          //receivedChar =(char)SerialBT.read();
           //if(receivedChar != turnBLINK){
         // break;
          // } else {
          digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);// turn the LED off 
          delay(1000);
          digitalWrite(LEDpin,LOW);
          delay(1000);
           if(receivedChar != turnBLINK){
                 break;    }  
    
     }
        }
      }
    delay(20);
    }
```

and with case:

```c++
    #include "BluetoothSerial.h"
    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <analogWrite.h>
    
    #if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
    #error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
    #endif
    
    BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
    
    int received;// received value will be stored in this variable
    char receivedChar;// received value will be stored as CHAR in this variable
    char data;
    int option;
    int blink=0;
    const int LEDpin = 12;
    
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
      SerialBT.begin("Mono"); //Bluetooth device name
      Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
      Serial.println("To turn ON send: 1");//print on serial monitor  
      Serial.println("To turn OFF send: 0"); //print on serial monitor 
     pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
     }
    
    
    void loop(){
       receivedChar =(char)SerialBT.read();
        
     // if (Serial.available()) {
      //  SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
      
    //  }
      if (SerialBT.available()) {
       // while(SerialBT.available()){
      //  receivedChar =(char)SerialBT.read();
      //  }
        
        SerialBT.print("Received:");// write on BT app
        SerialBT.println(receivedChar);// write on BT app      
        Serial.print ("Received:");//print on serial monitor
        Serial.println(receivedChar);//print on serial monitor    
        //SerialBT.println(receivedChar);//print on the app    
        //SerialBT.write(receivedChar); //print on serial monitor
     
      data=receivedChar;
      if(data == '0')
      {
        option = 0;
        blink=0;
      }else if(data == '1')
      {
        option = 1;
        blink=0;
      }else if(data == '2')
      {
        option = 2;
        blink=1;
      }
      switch (option)
      {
        case 0: // LED OFF
          digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);
        break;
        case 1: //LED ON
          digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);
        break;
        case 2:
        while(blink=1){// LED BLINK
          digitalWrite(LEDpin , HIGH);
          delay(200);
          digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);
          delay(200);
        }
          break;
        
      }
    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should clean your code to a minimum reproducible example. Remove all unnecessary comments and pieces of code that do not represent the main problem you are facing.

After a quick skim over your code, I immediately noticed this:

```
while(blink=1){// LED BLINK
      digitalWrite(LEDpin , HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);
      delay(200);
 }
```

where it should be `while(blink==1){ }` --> very common mistake. This should be a comparison, NOT an assignment.

Now, you mention that it never stops running. Even after correcting the error I just pointed at, what part inside of your while loop breaks the logic of `blink` from being equal to 1? Otherwise, the while-loop will never stop

Finally, do not read the serial data inside the main `loop()`. Use [SerialEvent](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent), rather.

Again, it is quite tricky to follow the flow of your code. I suggest you divide your code into functions in order to make it more readable.